# ASP.NET Core OData Batch works for get but not update (PATCH)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

Using .NET Core 3.1 and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` 8.0.4.

I've set up Batch on my API and it works if all the requests in the batch are GET.

But if I put any updates, it fails with an error I can't figure out.

Successful direct update:

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'https://localhost:44390/api/odata/TradeTypeSpread(8432C89B-6D71-48B2-9F40-0000190AD326)' \
--header 'ApiAccessKey: xxxx' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "Id":"8432C89B-6D71-48B2-9F40-0000190AD326",
    "Spread": 3.0
}'
```

```
200 OK
{
    "error": null,
    "isSucceeded": true,
    "id": null
}
```

Failed batch update:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost:44390/api/Odata/$batch' \
--header 'ApiAccessKey: xxx' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "requests": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "method": "PATCH",
            "url": "/api/odata/TradeTypeSpread(8432C89B-6D71-48B2-9F40-0000190AD326)",
            "body": {
                "Id": "8432C89B-6D71-48B2-9F40-0000190AD326",
                "Spread": 3.0
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

```
{
    "responses": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "status": 400,
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true",
                "odata-version": "4.0"
            },
            "body": {
                "error": {
                    "code": "",
                    "message": "The input was not valid.",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "code": "",
                            "message": "The input was not valid."
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong in the second sample?

Startup Code:

```
        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            var defaultODataBatchHandler = new DefaultODataBatchHandler();
            defaultODataBatchHandler.MessageQuotas.MaxNestingDepth = 2;
            defaultODataBatchHandler.MessageQuotas.MaxOperationsPerChangeset = 100;


            services
                .AddControllersWithViews(options =>
                {
                    options.Filters.Add(typeof(HttpGlobalExceptionFilter));
                    options.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidateModelStateAttribute));
                })
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.UseDefaultSettings(nullValueHandling: Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Include))
                .AddOData(opt => opt.AddRouteComponents(
                                    "api/odata",
                                     new ModuleOdataEntityDataModel().GetEntityDataModel(),
                                     defaultODataBatchHandler)
                                    .Select().Filter().Count().OrderBy().Expand().SetMaxTop(Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["OdataMaxPageSize"])))
                .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
                });
```

Controller Code

```
 public class TradeTypeSpreadController : ODataController
    {


        [EnableQuery]
        public async Task<IQueryable<TradeTypeSpreadDto>> Get()
        {
            ...
        }

        

        public async Task<IActionResult> Patch(Guid key, Delta<TradeTypeSpreadDto> detalTradeSpreadDto)
        {
            ...
        }


    }
```

Thanks
Sam

Comment: You can follow this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapiauth/getting-started, also how does your controller API code look like?

Comment: Hi Chaodeng,
Yes I followed something similar.  The reason I didn't put my startup code, is that all the individual Get and Update logic works.  It's only Batch Update that has an issue.  But let me add the relevant code above now.

Comment: Done, added the missing code.

Comment: For me I had to use single quotes around the Guid _Key_ in the URL but otherwise with that setup it just worked.

Answer (score 0):

Working batch update for OData in ASP Net Core might look like this:

```
    [AcceptVerbs("PATCH", "MERGE")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Patch(
        [FromODataUri] string key,
        Delta<MyModel> patch)
    {
            var model = patch.GetInstance();
            await _repository.Update(model);

            // IQueryable
            var res = _repository.GetAll().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == key); 

            return Updated(res);
    }
```

And it expects "get single" to be available as well:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get(
        [FromODataUri] string key)
    {
        var dataset = _salesAreaBandsRepository.GetAll();

        return Ok(dataset.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == key));
    }
```

And of course the GetEdmModel() has to be adjusted if you use compound key or other field as a key:

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    var entitySet1 = builder.EntitySet<MyModel>("MyModel");
    entitySet1.EntityType.HasKey(entity => entity.OtherKey);
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

And you have:

```
app.UseODataBatching();
```

Sometimes you also need to change `AddRouteComponents`:

```
AddRouteComponents("odata", GetEdmModel(),
                    new DefaultODataBatchHandler())
```